# How to read column wise in excel using java?

Tags: java, apache-poi

If suppose excel having date value format in any column means, I need to change the whole column as date format and insert "N/A" value in an empty record of the date column. Anyone, please help me to solve this.

Comment: There are lot of examples available at http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/examples.html - May be you can try writing the code and update the question with code if you face any issues?

Comment: Maybe you can post a sample Excel that you receive and what it should look like after you change it.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void processExcelFromLocal() {

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(
                    new File("/home/rajat/Downloads/excelFile.xlsx"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        if (fis != null) {

            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
            try {
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            for (int i = 0; i <= spreadsheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
                XSSFRow row = spreadsheet.getRow(i);
                String value = row.getCell().getStringCellValue();    
            }
        }

        try {
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: how to give static value for column. i receive excel file which is having date column is multiple. non - standard (). how to resolve in program

Comment: you better format that using date formatter either in Google sheet or MS Excel program

Comment: do accept the answer if it has answered what is asked.

Comment: Start FFF DOB
06-06-1921 asdf 06-06-1921
 asdf 1-03-21
06-06-1921 sdg 
 d-dhkc 
 b-raja 01-01-2019
  
20-11-2011  
 dhdh 03-11-1893

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb9Ju.png)

this is the final output file. have to insert constant value in empty cells of date column without mentioning date column name. empty cells are highlighted as green colour.